# Masquerading with Warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, warden

In my Rails app I'm using Warden with my own strategy. I'm not using Devise.

As an administrator, I would now like to log in as another user by pressing a simple button.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, no, it depends. We know nothing about what your strategy does so there is no way to tell.

Comment: Is the administrator of the same class as the regular user? If so, this will make it harder to do masquerading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the Warden `set_user` method.

Check out [the Warden wiki](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Users#setting-the-user) for more info.